# Awesomium .NET: System.InvalidCastException: The JSValue Does Not Represent A Number

Tags: javascript, c#, awesomium

We're using some JavaScript to determine the height of the loaded WebView page and seeing a sporadic error (as per the title).

```
 private const string PageHeightFunc = @"
 (function() {
   var bodyElmnt = document.body;
   var html = document.documentElement;
   var height = Math.max( bodyElmnt.scrollHeight, bodyElmnt.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
   return height;
 })();";

 int height = (int)webView.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult( PageHeightFunc );
```

This work without issue but someone is seeing this error sporadically when we're rendering some web pages. I had a feeling that the JS code might be executing too early but it seems to execute after LoadingFrameComplete (for the main frame) using a WaitOne on a CompletionEvent so I don't think that's it.

Any ideas what might be causing this? :|

Comment: Have you checked what it returns and made sure it actually is an int and that it's executed?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't been able to repro the issue on my side so it's difficult to debug, otherwise that would have been my first thought.

Comment: Put up an exception handler around it and save the value returned from `ExecuteJavascriptWithResult` before casting it.

Comment: @Bauss Thanks, I've gone ahead and implemented some better error handling logic so we can get an idea of what's going on. It seems that the ExecuteJavascriptWithResult() function is returning an invalid value because the JS returns undefined.

Comment: Yeah, a heads up. If any of the values passed to `Math.max` are undefined, then it will return undefined. :)